# Horizontal menu?

Tags: wpf, menu

I want to create a horizontal menu across the top of my user control whose items fill the whole space horizontally. There are six items and it's one level only - so it's not really a menu as such.

Can I do this with a menu? Or am I better off with using a six column grid with a button per col, or even a horizontal stack panel? Here is what I have so far:

```
 <DockPanel>
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None">
        <Menu KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="DarkGray" Height="40">
            <MenuItem Header="_New"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Load" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Validate" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Import" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Export"/>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

Menu derives from `ItemsControl` so can just switch the ItemsPanel:

```
 <DockPanel>
    <DockPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="None">
        <Menu KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="DarkGray" Height="40">
          <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
              <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
          </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

            <MenuItem Header="_New"/>
            <MenuItem Header="_Load" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Validate" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Import" />
            <MenuItem Header="_Export"/>
        </Menu>
    </DockPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<Menu KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="DarkGray" Height="40">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Header="_New"/>
                <MenuItem Header="_Load" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Save" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Validate" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Import" />
                <MenuItem Header="_Export"/>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Edit">
                <MenuItem Header="Cut"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Paste" />
                </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
```

Hope this will help. you need to add Menu subitems within the MenuItem. it itself is o0f List type.

Comment: Sorry, no that isn't what I mean. I want a bar across the screen with the six commands evenly spaced. There are no sub items.