# Creating a drop-down menu with radio buttons

Tags: c#, wpf

I am creating a WPF application that has the ability to use different sorting algorithms. Currently, it can only use QuickSort, but I want to implement a functionality that allows the user to click on a drop-down menu, which will then display all the different types of sorting algorithms. When the user selects one, and the 'Sort' button is clicked, it will use that method.

**How can I create a drop-down menu with radio buttons as items inside, and only one radio button can be selected at a time?**

A rough sketch of what I'd like:
[image: sketch]

Have done a dig around on Google looking for answers, but all I can find are dead links and/or outdated methods. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1790858/dropdown-menu-in-wpf-toolbar) stack overflow page is similar to what I'm looking for, however instead of buttons inside the drop-down menu, I'm looking for radio buttons.

Comment: Why not just use a standard ComboBox? Everyone knows how it works. A ComboBox with radio buttons inside is just weird, confusing and unnecessary

Comment: @canton7 I honestly didn't know they existed. Relatively new to WPF, but I'm sad to say I think this is more of an issue with my stupidity. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You must have used a Windows application with a ComboBox in it before, and so know that they exist and what they look like?

Comment: @canton7 I'm very new to GUI programming. Mostly do Python command shell-type stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by @canton7, use a normal combo box. I would suggest starting out with the simplest possible version, without any fancy visual (like the checkbox in your drawing).

Google **"ComboBox WPF"** to get started.